# Powershell json to csv complex json file

Tags: json, powershell, csv, convertto-json

I'm trying to convert a complex json file into a csv file. I've tried a few things now and this query worked best, unfortunately I can't get the product to be displayed
The product to be displayed would be the following in the json file **"PRD_GV_BCA"**
Unfortunately, I only get the other values displayed with the query from one product and not from another. (Of course, also enter a product in the code below, don't know how I can use a placeholder there or that changes, I'm not that good with Powershell yet)

Hope you have an approach how I can do it differently

current result from Script
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXb5b.png)

that how it should looks like
[that how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byfHb.png)

```
$pathToJsonFile = "<Pfad zum Skript>\jsontocsv\tjson.json"
$pathToOutputFile = "<pfad zur Excel Datei>\jsontocsv\converts.csv"
((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile) | ConvertFrom-Json)  | ForEach-Object {
$Produkt = $_
$deckung += $_.PRD_GV_BCA | ForEach-Object {
[pscustomobject] @{
    'Produkt' = $Produkt
    'iconCode' = $_.iconCode
    'labelKey' = $_.labelKey
    'descriptionKey' = $_.descriptionKey
    'gedeckt' = $_.gedeckt
 }

}
write-host $deckung
}
$deckung | Export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

thats a part from the Input File, there more entries (roundabout 40 products and there sub entries

```
 {
        "PRD_GV_BCA": [{
                "iconCode": "custom:KVG.ArztwahlManagedCare",
                "labelKey": "ArztwahlManagedCare.label",
                "descriptionKey": "KVG.ArztwahlManagedCare.description",
                "gedeckt": true
        },
            {
                "iconCode": "custom:KVG.Franchise",
                "labelKey": "Franchise.label",
                "descriptionKey": "KVG.Franchise.description",
                "gedeckt": true
            },          {
                "iconCode": "custom:KVG.VVG.Versichertenkarte",
                "labelKey": "VersichertenkarteKVG.label",
                "descriptionKey": "KVG.VersichertenkarteKVG.description",
                "gedeckt": true
            }
        ],
        "PRD_GV_BEU": [{
                "iconCode": "custom:EGK-KVG_EU",
                "labelKey": "EU.label",
                "descriptionKey": "KVG.EU.description",
                "gedeckt": true
            },
            {
                "iconCode": "custom:KVG.VVG.Versichertenkarte",
                "labelKey": "VersichertenkarteKVG.label",
                "descriptionKey": "KVG.VersichertenkarteKVG.description",
                "gedeckt": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

Update:
with that Query i get the Product but not the rest. But also only one product

```
$pathToJsonFile = "<Pfad zum Skript>\jsontocsv\tjson.json"
$pathToOutputFile = "<Pfad zum Skript>\jsontocsv\converts.csv"
((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile) | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object {
$test = ($_ |out-string).trim()
$test2 = $test | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        'Produkt' = $test
        'iconCode' = $_.iconCode
        'labelKey' = $_.labelKey
        'descriptionKey' = $_.descriptionKey
        'gedeckt' = $_.gedeckt
        }
    }
}
$test2 | Export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

[result of the query where product is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EzTa.png)

Thanks for your help / support
regards
Chris

Answer (score 1):

By using `Out-String`, you get a multiline string which is no longer a set of objects with the data.

For this you will need to do some more loops over the objects properties like below:

```
$pathToJsonFile   = "<Pfad zum Skript>\jsontocsv\tjson.json"
$pathToOutputFile = "<Pfad zum Skript>\jsontocsv\converts.csv"

$deckung = Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($item in $_ ) {
        foreach ($produkt in $item.PsObject.Properties) {
            foreach ($detail in $produkt.Value) {
                [PsCustomObject] @{
                    Produkt        = $produkt.Name
                    iconCode       = $detail.iconCode
                    labelKey       = $detail.labelKey
                    descriptionKey = $detail.descriptionKey
                    gedeckt        = $detail.gedeckt
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# output to CSV file
$deckung | Export-Csv $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Note: by appending switch `-UseCulture` to the Export-Csv cmdlet, it will create a csv using the delimiter character your Excel expects, so you can simply double-click the file to get this result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Theo,
thanks for the Help, it Works for me. 
with your hint with the .Properties or .Value i was able to extend the query. 
I had one more level:

          ` <content product and co>
  "gedeckt": true,
  "kriterienAbhaengigeSelektion": [{
   "name": "PRD_FV_TOU_CTK_VH_TOU_V001",
   "value": "COD_VH_250"`
i add a if else 
                if($value.kriterienAbhaengigeSelektion.name){ <content> with AbhaengigeSelektion }  else {<content> without AbhaengigeSelektion }

regards 
Chris